# Git email notification

Tags: git, email, notifications

How to setup email notification for every commit locally or push to the git server?
Detailed description:
I want to trigger a mail to group of users for every push to the server.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [git hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)?

Comment: @Zeeker I didn't get you. where will I find git hooks?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the link I provided?

Answer (score 0):

Construct a script to create and send emails. I have used [this](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=110261). Put the script in the post-commit hook locally(to send email notification on every commit)  and post-receive hook on the remote (to send email notification on every push).

Do not forget to rename post-receive.sample to post-receive and same with post-commit!

Happy Gitting!

Comment: I checked my .git/hooks directory but in my hooks I don't have any post-commit.sample or post-receive.sample file. 
So do I need to create new file or some package needs to be installed?

Comment: Yes! You can create a shell script by name `post-receive` and `post-commit`

Which version of Git you use btw?

Comment: I am getting error like at 36 places: Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at .git/hooks/post-commit line 101 and Can't call method "mail" on an undefined value at .git/hooks/post-commit line 212 at 1 place. This error I am getting when running script post-commit.

Comment: @Abhishek: Kindly study the use of mail. As I told you I am using sendmail on my Linux server and it triggers mails fairly well.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can put the below code inside post-commit and post-receive hooks.

```
while read mailadd
do
   echo "This is a test mail" | mail ${mailadd} -s "test mail" -a file.txt
done < mailids.txt
```

mailids.txt is the file with will have mail IDs. (one ID in one line).

echo "This is a test mail" this is the email body
-s "test mail":  This is subject
-a file.txt : For sending any file as attachment

Answer (score 0):

[git-multimail](https://github.com/git-multimail/git-multimail) is meant exactly for that.

Warning: I'm the author.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [script](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=110261) from [Mudassir Razvi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2607581/mudassir-razvi)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25971688/6309), [the OP Abhishek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3842250/abhishek) adds in the comments:

> I am getting error like at 36 places: Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at .git/hooks/post-commit line 101

That error message will be more detailed/precise: An error message given by "[`git send-email`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/fa7a594daca938802bcd226713539e6a7f403095/Documentation/git-send-email.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-send-email))</sup> when given a malformed address did not give correct information, which has been corrected with Git 2.43 (Q4 2023).

See [commit 12288cc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/12288cc44e48810758b6d38b453b94568cb6fce3) (18 Sep 2023) by [Taylor Blau (`ttaylorr`)](https://github.com/ttaylorr).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit fa7a594](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fa7a594daca938802bcd226713539e6a7f403095), 22 Sep 2023)</sup>

> ### [`git-send-email.perl`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/12288cc44e48810758b6d38b453b94568cb6fce3): avoid printing undef when validating addresses
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Bagas Sanjaya</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> When validating email addresses with `extract_valid_address_or_die()`, we print out a helpful error message when the given input does not contain a valid email address.
>
> However, the pre-image of this patch looks something like:
>
> ```
> my $address = shift;
> $address = extract_valid_address($address):
> die sprintf(__("..."), $address) if !$address;
> ```
>
> which fails when given a bogus email address by trying to use $address (which is undef) in a sprintf() expansion, like so:
>
> ```
> $ git.compile send-email --to="pi <pi@pi>" /tmp/x/*.patch --force
> Use of uninitialized value $address in sprintf at /home/ttaylorr/src/git/git-send-email line 1175.
> error: unable to extract a valid address from:
> ```
>
> This regression dates back to [e431225](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e43122556912b02ec00746c4b528d7408da9a70f) ("`git-send-email`: remove invalid addresses earlier", 2012-11-22, Git v1.8.1-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/90583f17290db0a0e1007b2c32ca6637e7fbb07c)), but became more noticeable in [a8022c5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a8022c5f7b678189135b6caa3fadb3d8ec0c0d48) ("`send-email`: expose header information to git-send-email's sendemail-validate hook", 2023-04-19, Git v2.41.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b6e9521956b752be4c666efedd7b91bdd05f9756) listed in [batch #18](https://github.com/git/git/commit/91428f078b8a4fe6948a4c955af1a693841e3985)), which validates SMTP headers in the sendemail-validate hook.
>
> Avoid trying to format an undef by storing the given and cleaned address separately.
> After applying this fix, the error contains the invalid email address, and the warning disappears:
>
> ```
> $ git.compile send-email --to="pi <pi@pi>" /tmp/x/*.patch --force
> error: unable to extract a valid address from: pi <pi@pi>
> ```